# Install GDAL/OGR Python API on Debian

Tags: python, python-3.6, gdal, ogr

I trying to install Python GDAL/OGR bindings to be accessible directly from Python interpreter on Docker python:3.6-stretch image.

My Dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  binutils \
  libproj-dev \
  gdal-bin \
  libgdal-dev \
  python3-gdal \
  python3-pip \
  python-numpy \
  python-dev \
  vim

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt \
  && rm -rf /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
```

Dockerfile installs current stable version of GDAL and python3-gdal which is 2.1.2.

Import osgeo from Python interpreter gives me an error:

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

How to install neccessary libs properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing via Python PIP pygdal package. Firstly you need to check Gdal version installed on the machine, and install proper pygdal.

```
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
$ pip install "pygda>=2.1.2,<2.1.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using correct python 3 interpreter. You can call in linux system:

```
whereis python3
```

You had install python3-pip package, so you have osgeo in your main python 3 in /usr/bin/python3. In other python 3 locations osgeo can be not available.